# How do I add commits to a pull request someone sent me, if github tells me "Add more commits by pushing to the master branch on..."?

Tags: git, github, push, git-push, pull-request

Someone sent me a pull request. Github describes how to check out the branch and test the changes like this:

```
git checkout -b usernameOfPRSender-master master
git pull https://github.com/usernameOfPRSender/projectname.git master
```

This is what I did. Now I have the changes from the pull request locally, can look at them and test them locally.

I had to make some changes, so I performed the required changes and committed them.

How do I push to the pull request now?

Github tells me on the pull request page:

```
Add more commits by pushing to the master branch on usernameOfPRSender/projectname.
```

How can I do this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did

```
git push origin usernameOfPRSender-master:master
```

which seems to have worked (as described [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ffacww/editing-incoming-pull-requests)).

It merged all changes from the pull request and my changes and closed the pull request.